# Unused Office2016 ProPlus subscription licences

Tags: powershell, office365

In an effort to help reduce costs for the NFP organisation I work in, I'm hoping to find out which staff or volunteers have been assigned an Office2016 ProPlus subscription licence but not used it. (Managers tend to request it for all new starters regardless of job function, and such costs don't come out of their local budgets...)

Is it possible to identify users of licences that have been assigned but not used?

Sub-criteria that are not essential but would be nice are:

- Licensed users who haven't downloaded and installed the software from the Office365 Portal (there is a ["mostly-accurate" report](https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home#/reportsUsage/OfficeActivations); several of my users are definitely using the software long-term but the report claims no activation)
- Licensed users who have not run any of the Office applications on their PC (in the last three months)

I'm not particularly looking for a full scripted solution (although I'd never say no to one). Rather, useful pointers to appropriate Powershell commands, or even menu options and reports within the Office365 Administrator Portal would be wonderful.

I have looked around but nothing popped out at me other than finding [inactive users](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/364025-how-to-view-a-detail-report-of-inactive-users-in-office-365), seeing [which users](https://mymicrosoftexchange.wordpress.com/2015/03/23/office-365-script-to-get-detailed-report-of-assigned-licenses/) have been assigned [what licences](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/powershell/view-account-license-and-service-details-with-office-365-powershell), counting [unassigned subscriptions](https://gcits.com/knowledge-base/export-list-unused-office-365-licenses-delegated-administration-tenants/), and those I already keep at a minimal level (one or zero, usually).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the activity reports available in the Administration console?

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/activity-reports-in-the-office-365-admin-center-0d6dfb17-8582-4172-a9a9-aed798150263

**Update**

That information would not be available from Office 365 alone. You would need a third party solution which installs agents on each workstation to determine the exact usage of applications. Whilst I have yet to use it in a production environment, it sounds like Microsoft AppLocker might be worth looking into.

Comment: Hello George. https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home#/reportsUsage/OfficeActivations gets me a list of users who have activated the product, thank you. I can negate that to get a list of licensed users who have _not activated_ it, so I think that'll get me somewhere.

Comment: That's an interesting starting point but unfortunately doesn't help me find the users who activated it but simply don't use it. Thoughts appreciated...

Comment: How about the user level signon log in AzureAD?  I'm not sure if it logs just running the desktop application.